# VBA Code - Extract email addresses Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I got a code VBA code for extracting email addresses from PST files.
It is very useful as I can choose the folder to have the addresses extracted.
The code is extracting from the "**To**" field.

I need it to extract from the **message body** and also the "**From**" field.

What must I change in the code?

```
Sub ExtractEmail()
Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Mailobject As Object
Dim Email As String
Dim NS As NameSpace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
' Setup Namespace
Set NS = ThisOutlookSession.Session
' Display select folder dialog
Set Folder = NS.PickFolder
' Create Text File
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("c:\email addresses.txt", True)
' loop to read email address from mail items.
For Each Mailobject In Folder.Items
   Email = Mailobject.To
   a.WriteLine (Email)
Next
Set OlApp = Nothing
Set Mailobject = Nothing
a.Close
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you even try?... You have the mailItem object so use it to get the fields. Mailobject.Sender, Mailobject.SenderEmailAddress, Mailobject.SenderName and Mailobject.Body, Mailobject.HTMLBody or Mailobject.RTFBody

Comment: You are extracting the value of the To property, whcih is a ";" separated list of recipient names. You need to loop through all items in the MailItem.Recipients.Collection and for each recipient read the Recipient.Address property.

Comment: Thank you both. @Sorceri I was not sure on the labels that are used. Great help. Last, is it possible to make the code search in subfolders?

Comment: Can you help me with the code or point me somewhere to look for it so that it searches in subfolders? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have the mailItem object so use it to get the fields. Mailobject.Sender, Mailobject.SenderEmailAddress, Mailobject.SenderName and Mailobject.Body, Mailobject.HTMLBody or Mailobject.RTFBody –  Sorceri

You are extracting the value of the To property, whcih is a ";" separated list of recipient names. You need to loop through all items in the MailItem.Recipients.Collection and for each recipient read the Recipient.Address property. –  Dmitry Streblechenko

[Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)